# Configure preview for ObservedObject and State object

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I am still learning Swift and for some reason, I am having the hardest trouble with the previews and how to configure them.

So I have the following code:

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    // The app's model that the containing scene passes in
    @ObservedObject var model: MainViewModel
    @State var activeTab = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView(selection: $activeTab) {
                Group {
                    WorldView(model: model, activeTab: $activeTab)
                        .tabItem {
                            Label(Tabs.explore.rawValue, systemImage: Tabs.explore.icon)
                                .environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)
                        }
                        .tag(0)
                    ListView(model: model, activeTab: $activeTab)
                        .tabItem {
                            Label(Tabs.list.rawValue, systemImage: Tabs.list.icon)
                                .environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)
                        }
                        .tag(1)
                    FavoritesView(activeTab: $activeTab)
                        .tabItem {
                            Label(Tabs.favorite.rawValue, systemImage: Tabs.favorite.icon)
                                .environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)
                        }
                        .tag(2)
                    ProfileView(model: model, activeTab: $activeTab)
                        .tabItem {
                            Label(Tabs.profile.rawValue, systemImage: Tabs.profile.icon)
                                .environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)
                        }
                        .tag(3)
                }
                .environmentObject(model)
            }
            .tint(.accentColor)
            .onChange(of: activeTab, perform: { value in
                log.info("\n : (MainView: 46) - User has selected tab: \(value).")
                print("")
            })
        }
        .onAppear() {
            model.fetchPlaces()
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have the preview, as such:

```
struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainView(model: model, activeTab: activeTab)
    }
}
```

I am getting the two errors on the previews:

> Cannot find 'activeTab' in scope
> Cannot find 'model' in scope

If I define it as such:

```
struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @ObservedObject var model: MainViewModel
    @State var activeTab = 0
    static var previews: some View {
        MainView(model: model, activeTab: activeTab)
    }
}
```

I get the following errors:

> Instance member 'activeTab' cannot be used on type 'MainView_Previews'
> Instance member 'model' cannot be used on type 'MainView_Previews'

Does anyone know how I can configure the preview so that it works properly and doesn't crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are either passing in non existing paremeters in Previews, or because you cannot initialize objects in previews. Instead, do this:

```swift
struct MyExamplePreviews: PreviewProvider{
   static var previews: some View {
        MainView(model: MainViewModel(), activeTab: 0)
    }
}
```

This will allow you to preview the UI. What this does:

- Creates a new model that is passed in at the top level - again, you cannot create this anywhere but right here in the previews
- Makes it so that activeTab will be set to 0 -  you can have multiple preview devices with different tabs if needed. See the [docs for `Previews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/previews-in-xcode) to learn more.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for the explanation - Looks like I was over complicating things.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the below approach, then you can use `@EnvironmentObject var model: Model` in any View that needs it and don't have to pass it into every View.

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item] = []

    static var shared = Model()
    static var preview = Model(preview: true)

    init(preview: Bool) {
        if preview {
            items = // set some test items
            return
        }
        load()
    }

    fun load(){
        // load items from disk
    }
}
```

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(Model.shared)
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var: model: Model

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach($model.items) $item in {
                    TextField("Title" text: $item.title)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Items")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(Model.preview)
    }
}
```

Comment: how would this work? I keep getting an error that no member of 'shared' is present.

Comment: I added some code to demonstrate